# How get role inside another role oracle

Tags: oracle-12c

I am trying to make a script that allows me to get the roles that are inside another role of all users[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Granted roles are all in `dba_granted_roles`, so you can do a simple recursive query to get them.

I prefer `connect by` when I can get away with the simplicity:

```
select granted_role
      ,ltrim(sys_connect_by_path(granted_role,'>'),'>') how
from   dba_role_privs rp
connect by prior rp.granted_role = rp.grantee
start with rp.grantee = '<USER>'
```

I'm using `sys_connect_by_path` so each returned row tells me the route, e.g. for `SYS`

```
GRANTED_ROLE                   HOW
______________________________ __________________________________________________________________________________________________________
ACCHK_READ                     ACCHK_READ
ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK      ADM_PARALLEL_EXECUTE_TASK
APPLICATION_TRACE_VIEWER       APPLICATION_TRACE_VIEWER
AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE          AQ_ADMINISTRATOR_ROLE
AQ_USER_ROLE                   AQ_USER_ROLE
AUDIT_ADMIN                    AUDIT_ADMIN
AUDIT_VIEWER                   AUDIT_VIEWER
AUTHENTICATEDUSER              AUTHENTICATEDUSER
BDSQL_ADMIN                    BDSQL_ADMIN
BDSQL_USER                     BDSQL_USER
CAPTURE_ADMIN                  CAPTURE_ADMIN
CDB_DBA                        CDB_DBA
CONNECT                        CONNECT
DATAPATCH_ROLE                 DATAPATCH_ROLE
DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE     DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE
EXP_FULL_DATABASE              DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXP_FULL_DATABASE
EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE           DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE
HS_ADMIN_EXECUTE_ROLE          DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE>HS_ADMIN_EXECUTE_ROLE
HS_ADMIN_ROLE                  DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE>HS_ADMIN_ROLE
HS_ADMIN_EXECUTE_ROLE          DATAPUMP_EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXP_FULL_DATABASE>EXECUTE_CATALOG_ROLE>HS_ADMIN_ROLE>HS_ADMIN_EXECUTE_ROLE
...
```

You'll notice that some roles are granted via multiple other roles, you could do a simple `distinct` to remove duplicates here (of course you have to give up the route as this is what's making them distinct)

```
select distinct granted_role
from   dba_role_privs rp
connect by prior rp.granted_role = rp.grantee
start with rp.grantee = '<USER>'
```

Comment: Ty that helped me